# Can't mount NFS share in Big Sur. Crashes with NFSv4, rpc error with v3

Tags: mount, big-sur, nfs

I have an NFS mount being served from a Raspberry Pi that worked in prior versions of macOS.

I can see the mount on the remote server with `showmount`:

```
$ showmount -e 10.0.100.119                                                            
Exports list on 10.0.100.119:
/mnt/ssd/shared-nfs                 *
```

And rpcbind seems to show all the ports configured correctly:

```
$ rpcinfo -p 10.0.100.119 
   program vers proto   port
    100000    4   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   tcp    111  rpcbind
    100000    4   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    3   udp    111  rpcbind
    100000    2   udp    111  rpcbind
    100005    1   udp  54106  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  47295  mountd
    100005    2   udp  57827  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  49259  mountd
    100005    3   udp  54143  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  50115  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  44848  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  44848  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  44848  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  40361  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  40361  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  40361  nlockmgr
```

If I go into the Finder, press `CMD`+ `K` and connect to `nfs://10.0.100.119:/mnt/ssd/shared-nfs`, it gives an error in Console.app:

> nfs: STAT(NSM) rpc service is not available, unable to mount with current lock mode.

If I connect explicitly with NFSv4, with `nfs://vers=4,10.0.100.119:/mnt/ssd/shared-nfs`, Console.app shows ReportCrash `Saved crash report for mount_nfs[60875] version 150.40.3`, and if I view it, some of the relevant lines are:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [60875]

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                      10f907000-10f913000    [   48K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /sbin/mount_nfs

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   mount_nfs                       0x000000010f90c1da 0x10f907000 + 20954
1   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff204ca621 start + 1
```

I was also trying to mount the thing via the CLI (e.g. `mount -t nfs -o vers=4 10.0.100.119:/mnt/sshd/shared-nfs /Volumes/share`), but couldn't find any way to do it that didn't result in an error.

Comment: So far the only thing remotely related that I could find is [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252090404) on Apple Discussions, but that looks like an NFSv3 vs v4 issue. I can't connect with either :(

Comment: Found [another thread on MacRumors Forums](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/since-upgrading-to-big-sur-i-can-not-longer-mount-remote-nfs-drives.2274862/?post=29382871#post-29382871) that mentioned using `-o nolocks`, and that actually worked (but using v3 I presume)... but that's not a very fun/safe option.

Comment: Strange—today, I tried `sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4 10.0.100.119:/mnt/sas/shared-nfs ~/Downloads/nfsssd` and could get it to mount, but I was unable to copy any files between my Mac and the NFS mount (copies would just show "Preparing to copy" and never start).

Comment: I've the same problem with 11.3.1 (20E241). In any case it's a bug in OSX, hope it get fixed soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also updated my OS and it worked on the BigSur 11.6 with this command:

```
mount -o vers=4,resvport -t nfs xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/nfs/content /mnt/content/.
```

Comment: I was able to get it to mount this way, though I had to make sure the mount path existed on my Mac, and I had to run the command with `sudo` otherwise I got permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue is fixed in Big Sur 11.4 (20F71)